# .htaccess подмена картинки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Есть ссылка на картинку `somesite.ru/skins/Vasya.png`. Нужно в .htaccess отловить ссылку подобного вида, которая `/skins/` и `.png` и получить к скрипту слово `Vasya`. (По идеи можно его вычленять уже в самом скрипте) Нужно мне это, для того, чтобы подобные ссылки отдавали в итоге файл на сервере в малом регистре — `vasya.png`, а не все картинки на сайте. (Возможны и другие манипуляции в моем скрипте.) Нужно именно через .htaccess.

Comment: Интересный факт. Сковырнул регулярку на вообще все png файлы. В итоге: файл, например `somesite.ru/img/picture.png` ловится регуляркой, а вот в моем случае `somesite.ru/skins/Vasya.png` - нет. В чем может быть проблема папки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^skins/(.+)$ image.php?img=$1 [L]`

Comment: Не работает. Думаю проблема в том, что на пути к файлу 3 слеша встречается.

Comment: В любом случае открывается существующий файл, не реагирует скрипт. Вставил перед конструкцией `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Это идет уже после правила. Я выше написал, какая обнаружилась проблема. Воткнул вашу конструкцию прямо на 2 строку файла, сразу после `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Может у вас путь к картинке другой? `RewriteRule ^path/to/image/(.*)$ image.php?img=$1 [L]` или скрипт в другой папке

Comment: Путь то я поменял. Проблема вот в чем `RewriteRule ^(.*\.png)$` должна ловить абсолютно все .png файлы. (для примера), она и ловит! В любом месте на сервере .png файлы перенаправляются куда надо. А вот наша абстрактная папка не реагирует. То есть в ней тоже .png файл, но он не подчиняется этому правилу. Соответственно и вашему варианту она тоже не подчиняется. В кэшэ этих файлов нет, права на папке 777. Да и причем тут права...Сервер должен реагировать на стадии запроса.

Comment: Быть может в этой папке есть `.htaccess` файл, который каким то образом мешает работе основного? Можно так же глянуть `access.log` апача

Comment: Слезы, авации, радость...Да, в папке был .htaccess. В итоге все идеально заработало. Только добавил формат.
`RewriteRule ^skins/(.+)\.png$ skin.php?img=$1 [L]`